# Использование в макросах строковых литералов в качестве типов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, макросы, рефлексия

В классе есть метаинформация, представленная в виде вектора пар значений *строка-строка*, которые представляют собой строковое представление типа и имени члена класса.

Напрмиер:

```
class TObject
{
private:
    int  t_fMember;
    char t_sMember;
};
```

Для данного класса метаинформация представляется следующим множеством пар:

```
{
    {"int", "t_fMember"},
    {"char","t_sMember"}
}
```

Есть макрос, которые скрывает за собой шаблонную ф-ию:

```
#define GET_MEMBER_VALUE( MEM_TYPE, ... ) \
template <typename MEM_TYPE, ..> \
MEM_TYPE RetVal(...)\
{\
\
}
```

В сигнатуре и возвращаемом типе шаблонной ф-ии я писал не `MEM_TYPE`, а `##MEM_TYPE`, надеясь, что, например `"int"` превратится в `int`, однако, этого не произошло (чего и следовало ожидать).

Есть ли способ проводить подобную конверсию ? Передавать тип как строковый литерал, а затем делать обратное преобразование ? (`"type" -> type`)

UPD0: как бы я хотел это использовать:

```
#define GET_MEMBER_VALUE( MEM_TYPE, MEM_NAME, PTR_TO_OBJECT ) \
    template <typename MEM_TYPE, ..> \
    MEM_TYPE RetVal(...)\
    {\
        return PTR_TO_OBJECT->##MEM_NAME; \
    }
```

Отдаем указатель на объект, тип члена и его имя, обращаемся оператором `->` к члену по имени и возвращаем его значение.

Comment: А можете привести псевдокод того как вы хотите это использовать?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, сейчас обновлю вопрос, добавлю пример там.

Comment: Я имел ввиду пример использования самого макроса. Если вы пишете `GET_MEMBER_VALUE("int", "t_fMember", obj)`, то тогда просто уберите кавычки. Если, вы хотите, скажем, читать значения `"int"` и `"t_fMember"` из файла *на этапе выполнения*, то ничего не выйдет, потому что шаблоны инстанцируются *на этапе компиляции*

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, нет, я не могу просто убрать кавычки. Посмотрите еще раз на вопрос, пожалуйста. Это "метаданные", которые лежат, скажем, в векторе типа ```std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>>```, и эти самые "int" и "t_fMember" беруться оттуда.

Comment: Хорошо, скажите, а вот этот момент отработает так, как ожидаю ? ```PTR_TO_OBJECT->##MEM_NAME;```

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз на мой ответ, пожалуйста. Вектор по определению заполняется данными на ***этапе выполнения***. А шаблоны инстанцируются на ***этапе компиляции***

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, воу, извините пожалуйста, теперь понял, о чем Вы. Может вместо доступа по имени использовать доступ по _offset_ ?

Comment: Можно, а с типом как быть?:)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, эхх))

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, из строки с именем нельзя получить указатель на член класса, просто потому что в предложенной схеме хранения метаинформации отсутствую указатели на члены классов. Более развитые системы хранения метаинформации (например, BOOST.FUSION) это умеют.

```
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_c.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct TObject
{
    int  t_fMember;
    char t_sMember;
} ;

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        TObject,
        (int , t_fMember)
        (char, t_sMember)
        );

template<typename ReturnType, typename ObjectType>
struct memberByNameVisitor
{
    ObjectType* ptr;
    const char* seek_name;
    ReturnType** result;

    template<typename T>
    void visit_field( const char* field_name, T& field_value  ) const
    {}
    void visit_field( const char* field_name, ReturnType& field_value  ) const
    {
        if( strcmp( seek_name, field_name) ==0 )
            *result = & field_value;
    }


    template<typename Index>
    void operator() (Index idx) const
    {
        visit_field( boost::fusion::extension::struct_member_name<ObjectType,Index::value>::call(),
                     boost::fusion::at<Index>(*ptr) );
    }

};

template<typename ReturnType, typename ObjectType>
ReturnType& memberByName( ObjectType& ref, const char* name )
{
    typedef boost::mpl::range_c<unsigned, 0, boost::fusion::result_of::size<ObjectType>::value > Indices;
    ReturnType* result=nullptr;
    memberByNameVisitor<ReturnType, ObjectType> visitor={&ref, name, &result};
    boost::fusion::for_each( Indices(), visitor );

    if(result!=nullptr)
        return *result;
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Filed is not found");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TObject test ={ 1234, 'A' };
    std::cout << memberByName<int>( test, "t_fMember" ) << std::endl;
    memberByName<char>(test, "t_sMember") = 'C';
    std::cout << memberByName<char>(test, "t_sMember") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял Вас: что значит _нельзя получить указатель на член класса_ ... _отсутствуют указатели на члены классов_ ?

Comment: Про Boost.Fusion я слышал, но ситуация такова, что в проекте, где я хотел бы заюзать вещи, которые явились причиной создания это поста, нельзя использовать сторонние средства. Вот так вот (

Comment: Под "указатель на член класса" я имею ввиду точ что в стандарте обозначается  "pointer to member", т.е. указатели вида `int TObject* pointer = & TObject::t_fMember`. Эти указатели нужно включить в массив метеинформации. Проблема в том, что эти указатели имеют разный тип, в зависимости от типа члена на который указывают. Поэтому я и советую, по возможности, обойтись готовой реализацией. Подводных камней слишком много.

Comment: Извините, но пока что я не понимаю, зачем мне вообще нужны указатели на члены класса.

Comment: Это я к тому, что обращаться к членам класса я буду внутри класса.

Comment: Вам надо имея указатель на объект `TObject* p` получить указатель на данные `int * data`, хранимые в объекте. Есть три способа это сделать: (1) вызвать ` & (p->member) ` - требует знание имени члена в compile-time; (2) вызвать ` & (p->*pointer_to_member) `. Осталось получить из имени члена этот pointer_to_member. В случае если все происходит внутри класса - вместо p используем this ...

Comment: Я Вас понял, но я таки и собирался использовать вариант номер 2, поэтому и написал Вам - не пойму, зачем мне указатели на члены класса )